# How to convert "POSIXct" to a date object while also keeping time?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a set of dates and times stores in a vector called `START_DATE` in the following format

`"2016-11-07 10:45:48 UTC", "2016-11-07 10:48:01 UTC", "2016-11-07 10:48:02 UTC", "2016-11-07 10:49:59 UTC"`

when I type `class(phone_data$START_DATE)` is shows `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

I want to convert this into a date format but also keep the times

I tried the following

`as.Date(phone_data$START_DATE, tz = "UTC")`

However when I do this it gets rid of the times and I get something like the following

`"2016-11-07" "2016-11-07" "2016-11-07" "2016-11-07"`

How do I keep the date and the time in a single vector so that I can filter out certain rows that are above a certain date and time range

like `phone_data$START_DATE>"2016-11-07 10:48:01 UTC"`

Comment: I think the default format for `as.Date` is what you see. Is it possible that the time is also there, just not being displayed? Try a different `format` and see...

Comment: By definition a Date object is a date without the time portion.  A  POSIXct object is a date/time object is a date which includes a time portion.   This line of code will work with a Date or POSIXct object: `phone_data$START_DATE>"2016-11-07 10:48:01 UTC"`

Comment: From `?Date` (my emphasis): *Dates are represented as **the number of days** since 1970-01-01, with negative values for earlier dates.* Days since a base date, not seconds.

Comment: @Dave2e and Nathan123, technically that's doing a *string-comparison*, not an ordinal/continuous comparison. For example, this *should* be true but is not: `as.POSIXct("2019-08-18 00:01:00 -0400", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z") > "2019-08-18 00:00:00 +0000"`. The moral of this story: you cannot assume that comparison with a string will do as you intend.

Comment: (Contrast that last comment with: `as.POSIXct("2019-08-18 00:01:00 -0100", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z") > as.POSIXct("2019-08-18 00:00:00 +0000", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")`. Sorry for the lots-of-code-in-comment.)

Comment: My go-to way to perform that filter would be `library(lubridate); phone_data$START_DATE > ymd_hms("2016-11-07 10:48:01 UTC")`

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at the documentation of [strptime](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/strptime)

```
START_DATE <- c("2016-11-07 10:45:48 UTC", "2016-11-07 10:48:01 UTC", "2016-11-07 10:48:02 UTC", "2016-11-07 10:49:59 UTC")

START_DATE <- strptime(START_DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")
```

and then you can run the test as below

```
START_DATE>"2016-11-07 10:48:01 UTC"
```

Comment: This is wrong, unfortunately. Your comparison of `START_DATE` is to a *string*, not to a `Date` or `POSIXt` object. This *can* work if done right (meaning: it is feasible to do an alphabetic comparison of timestamps), but only if they are structured correctly. Having `UTC` in the string (specifically, anything hour-centric occurring after minutes) is not structured correctly.